# it possible to Pass Data with popViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I came across an interesting problem, i have main ViewController let's call him MainVC with navigationController and i am doing performSegueWithIdentifier from him to Mine second ViewController let's call him SecVC. so when i am trying to do the popViewControllerAnimated i want to pass some data from the SecVC to the MainVc.. i know i can do it with appDelegate Param or with singletons class but my question is : can i do it with more Elegant solution? like i use prepareForSegue and use local parmeters..

Thank you...

Comment: As per my knowledge it's not possible. you have to tak either golabla variable to store your data or store it in user defaults.

Comment: i will .. i want to try without :(

Comment: here is a TRUE way to use the delegate with popViewControllerAnimated in Swift!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692791/swift-how-to-call-delegate-with-popviewcontroller

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best way to do it is by using a delegate.

***//SecVCDelegate.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol SecVSDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)secVCDidDismisWithData:(NSObject*)data;
@end
```

***//SecVC.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecVSDelegate.h"

@interface SecVC : UIViewController

/** Returns the delegate */
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id<SecVSDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

***//SecVC.M***

```
...

- (void) dealloc
{
...
delegate = nil
...
}
```

When ever you popViewControllerAnimated, right after it (or before it) you do this

```
if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(secVCDidDismisWithData:)])
{
[_delegate secVCDidDismisWithData:myDataObject];
}
```

And in the MainVC you must be certain that you implement the delegate function 
***//MainVC.m***

```
- (void)secVCDidDismisWithData
{
//do whatever you want with the data
}
```

To avoid any warnings you must tell that the MainVC class implements the delegate like this:

***//MainVC.h***

```
#import "SecVCDelegate.h"
...
@interface MainVC : UIViewController <SecVCDelegate>
...
secVCInstance.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secVCInstance]; 
...
```

Comment: I did as you said. But why this is not working ? Where should i do something wrong ?

Comment: @alicanbature - be sure in MainVC before `pushViewController` that you set `SecVC.delegate = self;` which wasn't mentioned in this answer

Comment: yep you're right @thefoyer, i just edited my answer to add it

Answer (score 16):

While I agree that the best option is to use **Delegate**, 
but still if any one is looking for something different, he can use **NSNotificationCenter** as an alternative.

In **viewDidLoad** of MainVC:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(recvData:)
                                             name:@"SecVCPopped"
                                           object:nil];
}
```

And add method **recvData** in MainVC.m

```
- (void) recvData:(NSNotification *) notification
{

    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    int messageTotal = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"total"] intValue];
    NSLog (@"Successfully received data from notification! %i", messageTotal);
}
```

Now in SecVC, before popping, add this line

```
NSMutableDictionary* userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[userInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:messageTotal] forKey:@"total"];

NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc postNotificationName:@"SecVCPopped" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in one of the following ways, but I'm not sure if it's elegant enough...

1. In SecVC, add an `@property MainVC *mainVC;` Use `[self.mainVC setSomeValue:...];` before calling `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:...];`
2. Use [self.navigationController viewControllers]; to find out the `MainVC *mainVC`, and call `[mainVC setSomeValue:...];` before the line of code that pop the `ViewController`.

Is this what you want?

Comment: This is not so clear for me.. will you please explain it

Comment: @DivineChild, I think delegate method suggested by Saliom is a better way to do it than my answer. Please see his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I simply set up a protocol in the view being dismissed (example in Swift):

```
 protocol ExampleTableViewControllerDismissDelegate {
    func didDismiss(withData: Any)
}

var delegate: SearchableTableViewControllerDismissDelegate?
```

You can then call this when you dismiss/pop your view like this

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
delegate?.didDismiss(withData: Any)
```

Then in the view being dismissed to (the parent in the hierarchy), we can conform to the delegate and essentially get a callback with the data after the view has been dismissed.

```
//MARK: ExampleTableViewControllerDismissDelegate

func didDismiss(withData: Any) {
    //do some funky stuff
}
```

And don't forget to subscribe to the delegate in the parent view by using

```
viewController.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to pass data between views including **popViewControllerAnimated** and it's with a global var instance, so If you modify that Var in your detail view and after do the **popViewControllerAnimated**, you can call the new data in the viewWillAppear method.

The first step is declare the Global var in main.h

```
NSMutableArray * layerList;
```

And now you have to call it in detail view.

**SecondView.m**

```
extern NSString *layerList;
```

**SecondView.h**

```
-(void)back{
    layerList = @"Value to send";
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now you can use the information in the Master View after detect the pop action.

**FirstView.m**

```
extern NSString *layerList;
```

**FirstView.h**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   NSLog(@"This is what I received: %@",layerList);
}
```