# Swift – Using popViewController and passing data to the ViewController you're returning to

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationcontroller

I have an optional `bool` variable called `showSettings` on my first view controller which is called `ViewController`, and I'm popping from `SecondViewController` back to `ViewController`.

Before I pop, I want to set the bool to true. Seems wrong to instantiate another view controller since `ViewController` is in memory.

What's the best way to do this? I'm not using storyboards, if that's important for your answer.

Thanks for your help

Comment: the answer that you are looking for is on this post 

[it possible to Pass Data with popViewControllerAnimated?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509832/it-possible-to-pass-data-with-popviewcontrolleranimated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I figured it out, based mostly from this post – http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/15/swift-swift-programmatic-navigation-view-controllers-in-swift/

In `SecondViewController`, above the class declaration, add this code:

```
protocol SecondVCDelegate {
    func didFinishSecondVC(controller: SecondViewController)
}
```

Then inside of `SecondViewContoller` add a class variable:

`var delegate: MeditationVCDelegate! = nil`

Then inside of your function that your button targets, add this:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
delegate.didFinishSecondVC(self)
```

What we're doing here is doing the pop in `SecondViewController`, and *not* passing any data, but since we've defined a protocol, we're going to use that in `ViewController` to handle the data.

So next, in `ViewController`, add the protocol you defined in `SecondViewController` to the list of classes `ViewController` inherits from:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SecondVCDelegate { ... your code... }
```

You'll need to add the function we defined in the new protocol in order to make the compiler happy. Inside of `ViewController`'s class, add this:

```
func didFinishSecondVC(controller: SecondViewController) {
    self.myBoolVar = true
    controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

In `SecondViewController` where we're calling `didFinishSecondVC`, we're calling this method inside of the `ViewController` class, the controller we're popping to. It's similar to if we wrote this code inside of `SecondViewController` but we've written it inside of `ViewController` and we're using a delegate to manage the messaging between the two.

Finally, in `ViewController`, in the function we're targeting to *push* to `SecondViewController`, add this code:

```
let secondVC = secondViewController()
secondVC.delegate = self
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)
```

That's it! You should be all set to pass code between two view controllers without using storyboards!

Comment: I believe `var delegate: MeditationVCDelegate! = nil` should be `var delegate: SecondVCDelegate! = nil`, right?

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you Zack!

Answer (score 16):

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        let previousViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last as! PreviousViewController
        previousViewController.PropertyOrMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this while looking for a way to do it.  Since I use Storyboards more often, I found that I can get the array of controllers in the navigation stack, get the one just before the current one that's on top, check to see if it's my delegate, and if so, cast it as the delegate, set my methods, then pop myself from the stack.  Although the code is in ObjC, it should be easily translatable to swift:

```
// we need to get the previous view controller
NSArray *array = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
if ( array.count > 1) {
    UIViewController *controller = [array objectAtIndex:(array.count - 2)];
    if ( [controller conformsToProtocol:@protocol(GenreSelectionDelegate)]) {
        id<GenreSelectionDelegate> genreDelegate = (id<GenreSelectionDelegate>)controller;
        [genreDelegate setGenre:_selectedGenre];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon the answer by Abdul Baseer Khan:

For cases where the current view controller may have been loaded by different types of previous view controller, we can use the safer `as?` call instead of `as!`, which will return `nil` if the controller is not what we were looking for:

```swift
let previousVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last as? AnExampleController
previousVC?.doSomething()
```

Although, you would need to repeat that for each different view controller that could load the current view controller.

So, you may want to, instead, implement a protocol to be assigned to all the possible previous view controllers:

```swift
protocol PreviousController: UIViewController {
  func doSomething()
}

class AnExampleController: UIViewController, PreviousController {
  // ...
  func doSomething() {}
}

class AnotherController: UIViewController, PreviousController {
  // ...
  func doSomething() {}
}

class CurrentController: UIViewController {
  // ...
  func goBack() {
    let previousVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.last as? PreviousController
    previousVC?.doSomething()
  }
}
```