# how to call popviewcontroller in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, popviewcontroller

The current structure is

firstViewController -> pushViewController(SecondViewController)

```
-UIViewController      ->filename :  secondViewController

    -UITableView        


        -UITableViewCell (custom cell)     ->filename :  secondTableViewCell

            -UICollectionView                


                -UICollectionViewCell (custom cell)      ->filename : secondCollectionViewCell
```

When 'didSelectItemAt' is done in the 'UICollectionView'

I would like to call the 'popviewcontroller' from UIViewController.

And I want to pass the data on the selected item to firstViewController.

but i don't know how

** ViewController **

```
struct cellStat{
var opened = Bool()
var title = String()
var sectionData = [ItemModel]()
}

//선물 카테고리 리스트 보여주는 모달
class GiftCategoryModalVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

private var categoryTitleModels: [ItemModel] = []
private var giftItemModels: [ItemModel] = []
private var titleCellData: [cellStat] = []

//LIFE CYCLE
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: GiftCategoryTBCell.reusableIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: GiftCategoryTBCell.reusableIdentifier)
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: GiftCategoryListTBCell.reusableIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: GiftCategoryListTBCell.reusableIdentifier)

    //get gift categofy title
    GiftPageAPIService.shared.selectCode(code: "CD005") { (itemModels) in
        self.categoryTitleModels = itemModels
        itemModels.forEach { (itemModel) in
            self.titleCellData.append(cellStat(opened: false, title: itemModel.codeNm!, sectionData: []))
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    setupLayout()
}

//LAYOUT
fileprivate func setupLayout(){
    setNavbar()
}

fileprivate func setNavbar(){
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_arrow_left"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleEndButton))
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(hex: 0xececec)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(hex: 0x979797)
}


//MAKR:- ACTION
@objc func handleEndButton(){
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

}




extension GiftCategoryModalVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if titleCellData[section].opened == true{
        return 2
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return titleCellData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GiftCategoryTBCell.reusableIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GiftCategoryTBCell
        cell.setCategotyNm = categoryTitleModels[indexPath.section].codeNm

        if titleCellData[indexPath.section].opened == true{
            cell.setImgView = UIImage(named: "arrow_up")
        }else{
            cell.setImgView = UIImage(named: "arrow_down")
        }
        return cell
    }else{
//this cell is call tableCell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: GiftCategoryListTBCell.reusableIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GiftCategoryListTBCell
        cell.setItems = titleCellData[indexPath.section].sectionData

        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        if titleCellData[indexPath.section].opened == true{
            titleCellData[indexPath.section].opened = false
            let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
            tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic)
        }else{
            titleCellData[indexPath.section].opened = true
            GiftPageAPIService.shared.selectCode(code: categoryTitleModels[indexPath.section].codeCd!) { (items) in

                self.titleCellData[indexPath.section].sectionData = items
                let sections = IndexSet.init(integer: indexPath.section)
                tableView.reloadSections(sections, with: .automatic)
            }
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0{
        return 50
    }else{
        let cellHeight: Int = (titleCellData[indexPath.section].sectionData.count + 2) / 3
        return self.view.frame.height * 0.24 * CGFloat(cellHeight)
    }
}
}
```

** TableViewCell **

```
class GiftCategoryListTBCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
var items: [ItemModel]?
var category: ItemModel?

var setCategory: ItemModel?{
    didSet{
        self.category = setCategory!
        getCategoryData()
    }
}

var setItems: [ItemModel]?{
    didSet{
        self.items = setItems!
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}


let flowlayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: GiftItemCVCell.reusableIdentifier, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: GiftItemCVCell.reusableIdentifier)

    setupLayout()

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

//MARK:- LAYOUT
fileprivate func setupLayout(){
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: 0xf7f7f7)
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
}

fileprivate func getCategoryData(){
    GiftPageAPIService.shared.selectCode(code: (category?.codeCd)!) { (items) in
        self.items = items
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

}


extension GiftCategoryListTBCell: UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if items == nil{
        return 0
    }else{
        return (items?.count)!
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: GiftItemCVCell.reusableIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! GiftItemCVCell
    cell.setItem = items?[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    /*

        I tried to do the work here.

    */
}
}


extension GiftCategoryListTBCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: contentView.frame.width * 0.07, left: contentView.frame.width * 0.07, bottom: contentView.frame.width * 0.07, right: contentView.frame.width * 0.07)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return contentView.frame.width * 0.03
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = (contentView.frame.width) * 0.25
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width * 1.5)
}

}
```

Comment: here you need to write blocks and pass data using it. need to write block in collectionView - tableviewCell- tableview - vc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift – Using popViewController and passing data to the ViewController you're returning to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30971675/swift-using-popviewcontroller-and-passing-data-to-the-viewcontroller-youre-re)

Comment: i wanna know about 'how to call popviewcontroller at UITableViewCell'
I do not know how to call popviewcontroller on uitableviewcell.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

window?.topMostWindowController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

Create a protocol in the tableviewcell file

```
class myTableCell: UITableViewCell{
    var myString = "mystring"
    var delegate = myNewDelegate?

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        delegate?.didSelect(text: self.myString)
    } 

}


protocol myNewDelegate {
   func didSelect(text: String)
}
```

This goes in the view controller class that the table cell is in.

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, myNewDelegate{

    var stringToPass = String()

    func didSelectText(text: String){
        stringToPass = text
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "editProfileSegue", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
      if segue.identifier == "editProfileSegue"{
         let viewcontroller = segue.destination as! FirstViewController

         viewcontroller.myPassedString = self.stringToPass

        }
    }
}
```

And then id the receiving class

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController{
    var myPassedString = String()
}
```

Comment: I think this will segue to destination as A new controller not to previous controller present in stack , Correct  me if I am wrong

Comment: Your are correct, the question is kind of confusing but my understanding is that he would would a new instance of viewcontoller to be created but maybe not

Answer (score 0):

I understand what your mean.

If you want to pop your controller to previous controller in tablecell just to get its viewcontroller which control the cell and try to pop and if you try this method, why not override delegate func in your viewcontroller ?May a little bit hard to read the code, but useful, and you can use

```
self.navigationcontroller?.popViewController
```

If you have already use the viewcontroller to delegate the other tableview, just to judge the tableview name in your delegate func

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if tableView == blah blah 
     {
           do what you want
     }
}
```

And if you need to pass the data between the different viewController especially pass the data to pre-viewController you need to write delegate, or need to __block callback.