# Swift / how to call delegate with popViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30618172/how-to-send-data-back-by-popviewcontrolleranimated-for-swift) (and similar others) from bottom to top, but it doesn't fit my needs at all.

I have a `UIViewController` inside `UIPageViewController` within a `UINavigationController`. Navigating to a 2nd ViewController. Navigating to a 3rd ViewController and want to pop back to 2nd ViewController delivering data.

My code currently:

```
protocol PassClubDelegate {
            func passClub(passedClub: Club)
        }

class My3rdVC: UIViewController {

        var clubs: [Club] = []

        var passClubDelegate: PassClubDelegate?

....

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let club = clubs[indexPath.row]
        self.passClubDelegate?.passClub(club)
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

My 2nd VC:

```
class My2ndVC: UIViewController, PassClubDelegate {

    var club = Club()

    func passClub(passedClub: Club) {

        SpeedLog.print("passClub called \(passedClub)")
        club = passedClub
    }
```

`passClub` is not called. I'm sure it's because I didn't set the delegate to the My2ndVC, but how would I do that? All the solutions I have found wanting me to use a) segue or b) instantiate a My2ndVC new, what doesn't make any sense since it's still in memory and I want to pop back to go back in hierarchy. What am I missing? What are my possibilities? Help is very appreciated.

**PS**: I'm not using any segues. My3rdVC is called by:

```
let vc = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("My3rdVC") as! My3rdVC
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: but iam not pushing but poping a view controller so what should i do that?

Comment: do you still need help with this? @iOSDeveloper

Comment: yes i need help @David

Comment: i will write a medium article in a couple hours and post it here. will be done in around 4-6 hours max

Comment: here @iOSDeveloper https://medium.com/@davidseek1986/swift-101-delegate-and-uinavigationcontroller-39536787d076

Comment: thanx @David Seek.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the delegate of `My3rdVC` in the `prepareForSegue` method of  `My2ndVC`.

```
class My2ndVC: UIViewController, PassClubDelegate {

    ...

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)

        switch segue.destinationController {
        case let controller as My3rdVC:
            controller.passClubDelegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming you have created a segue in your storyboard that pushes  `My3rdVC` from `My2ndVC` onto the navigation controller stack, which I'm assuming you have. So just try simply pasting this `prepareForSegue` method into `My2ndVC` and see if it works.

*UPDATE*

```
let vc = stb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("My3rdVC") as! My3rdVC

vc.passClubDelegate = self

navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I'm not using any segues.

Comment: You can pass the delegate after instantiating `My3rdVC` but before pushing it onto the navigation controller stack

Comment: I've posted your answer into the other threads (just into the comment, as link). hope you're getting more likes

Comment: but iam not pushing but poping a view controller so what should i do that?

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Did you find any answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

When pop one VC to another you can pass data using protocol by declare delegate variable as static. Here in the following example we pop SecondVC to FirstVC and we pass a string.

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController,getDataDelegateProtocol {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        SecondVC.delegate = self
    }
    
    func getData(tempStr: String) {
        label.text = tempStr
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton){
        let nav = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nav, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Another View Controller

```
protocol getDataDelegateProtocol{
    func getData(tempStr: String)
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    static var delegate: getDataDelegateProtocol?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonClick(_ sender: UIButton){
        SecondVC.delegate?.getData(tempStr: "Received data from SecondVC")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```